# 'azure.iot.device.common.transport_exceptions.ConnectionDroppedError: Unexpected disconnection\n'

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub

I have multiple devices on Azure IOT hub, which I am trying to connect, send telemetry message and disconnect. This process is happening in multithread operation i.e., each device's operation is taking place in single thread. After connecting to device, I am getting

*Exception caught in background thread.  Unable to handle.*

*['azure.iot.device.common.transport_exceptions.ConnectionDroppedError: Unexpected disconnection\n']
until I call client.disconnect()*

Even though the device shows connected on the IOT Explorer.
How to avoid this error?
Logs:

```
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:disconnected with result code: 7
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:  File "C:\Users\mpatle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 930, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3591, in _thread_main
    self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1756, in loop_forever
    rc = self._loop(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1164, in _loop
    rc = self.loop_read()
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1558, in loop_read
    return self._loop_rc_handle(rc)
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 2350, in _loop_rc_handle
    self._do_on_disconnect(rc, properties)
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3475, in _do_on_disconnect
    on_disconnect(self, self._userdata, rc)
  File "C:\Users\mpatle\source\repos\GetliveSvanNt\env\lib\site-packages\azure\iot\device\common\mqtt_transport.py", line 209, in on_disconnect
    logger.debug("".join(traceback.format_stack()))

INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Forcing paho disconnect to prevent it from automatically reconnecting
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:in paho thread.  nulling _thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Done forcing paho disconnect
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Failing all subscribes and unsubscribes outstanding
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_mqtt_disconnected in pipeline thread
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage: _on_mqtt_disconnect called: The connection was lost.
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage(DisconnectedEvent): State changes CONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED. Attempting to reconnect
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:PipelineRootStage: DisconnectedEvent received. Calling on_disconnected_handler
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_disconnected in callback thread
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage: Unexpected disconnect (no pending connection op)
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.abstract_clients:Connection State - Disconnected
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:PipelineRootStage: BackgroundExceptionEvent received. Calling on_background_exception_handler
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.abstract_clients:Cleared all pending method requests due to disconnect
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_background_exception in callback thread
WARNING:azure.iot.device.common.handle_exceptions:Exception caught in background thread.  Unable to handle.
WARNING:azure.iot.device.common.handle_exceptions:['azure.iot.device.common.transport_exceptions.ConnectionDroppedError: Unexpected disconnection\n']
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_reconnect_timer_expired in pipeline thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage: Reconnect timer expired. State is ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED.
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage: Starting reconnection
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage: State changes ConnectionState.DISCONNECTED -> CONNECTING. Sending new connect op down in reconnect attempt
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage(ConnectOperation): connecting
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage(ConnectOperation): Starting watchdog
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:connecting to mqtt broker
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Connect using port 8883 (TCP)
DEBUG:paho:Sending CONNECT (u1, p1, wr0, wq0, wf0, c0, k60) client_id=b'SvanNet92810'
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:_mqtt_client.connect returned rc=0
DEBUG:paho:Received CONNACK (1, 0)
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:connected with result code: 0
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_mqtt_connected in pipeline thread
DEBUG:paho:Sending PUBLISH (d1, q1, r0, m1), 'b'devices/SvanNet92810/messages/events/'', ... (25981 bytes)
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:_on_mqtt_connected called
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage(ConnectedEvent): State changes CONNECTING -> CONNECTED. Connection established
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:PipelineRootStage: ConnectedEvent received. Calling on_connected_handler
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_connected in callback thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage: completing connect op
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.abstract_clients:Connection State - Connected
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage(ConnectOperation): cancelling watchdog
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:ConnectOperation: completing without error
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage(ConnectOperation): on_connect_complete error=None state=ConnectionState.CONNECTED
DEBUG:paho:Received PUBACK (Mid: 1)
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:payload published for 1
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Response received for recognized MID: 1 - triggering callback
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_complete in pipeline thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage(MQTTPublishOperation): PUBACK received. completing op.
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:MQTTPublishOperation: completing without error
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:SendD2CMessageOperation: Worker op (MQTTPublishOperation) has been completed
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:SendD2CMessageOperation: completing without error
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_complete in callback thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.evented_callback:Callback completed with result None
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Successfully sent message to Hub
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Disconnecting from Hub...
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Executing initial disconnect
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.pipeline.mqtt_pipeline:Starting DisconnectOperation on the pipeline
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting run_op in pipeline thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage(DisconnectOperation): State changes CONNECTED -> DISCONNECTING. Sending op down.
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage(DisconnectOperation): disconnecting
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:disconnecting MQTT client
DEBUG:paho:Sending DISCONNECT
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:disconnected with result code: 0
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Failing all subscribes and unsubscribes outstanding
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_mqtt_disconnected in pipeline thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:_mqtt_client.disconnect returned rc=0
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.mqtt_transport:Cancelling all pending operations
INFO:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage: _on_mqtt_disconnect called
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage(DisconnectedEvent): State changes DISCONNECTING -> DISCONNECTED. Not attempting to reconnect (User-initiated disconnect)
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:PipelineRootStage: DisconnectedEvent received. Calling on_disconnected_handler
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting _on_disconnected in callback thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_mqtt:MQTTTransportStage: Expected disconnect - completing pending disconnect op
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.abstract_clients:Connection State - Disconnected
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:DisconnectOperation: completing without error
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.abstract_clients:Cleared all pending method requests due to disconnect
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_complete in callback thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.evented_callback:Callback completed with result None
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Successfully executed initial disconnect
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Stopping handlers...
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Successfully stopped handlers
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Executing secondary disconnect...
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.pipeline.mqtt_pipeline:Starting DisconnectOperation on the pipeline
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting run_op in pipeline thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_stages_base:ConnectionStateStage(DisconnectOperation): State is already DISCONNECTED. Completing operation
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_ops_base:DisconnectOperation: completing without error
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.pipeline.pipeline_thread:Starting on_complete in callback thread
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.common.evented_callback:Callback completed with result None
DEBUG:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Successfully executed secondary disconnect
INFO:azure.iot.device.iothub.sync_clients:Successfully disconnected from Hub
Message sent to IoT Hub
```

I have tried immediately connecting and disconnecting the the device after sending telemetry message to the device, still getting same exception.

Code-

```
    try:
        if not hasattr(self, '_device_client') or not self._device_client:
            self._device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string)

        if not self._device_client.connected:
            self._device_client.connect()


        self._device_client.send_message(message)
        print("Message sent to IoT Hub")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

    finally:
        try:
            if self._device_client and self._device_client.connected:
                self._device_client.disconnect()
        except Exception as disconnect_error:
            print(f"Error while disconnecting from IoT Hub: {disconnect_error}")
```

I am getting errors immediately after the connect() is called-

```
if status == False:
    try:
            asyncio.run(device_instance.DPS_Device(device_key)) 
            #client.connect()
            Azure_instance.send_message(connection_string,message_payload)
            time.sleep(5)
           
            #client.connect()
            #client.shutdown()
            #if status == False:
            device_instance.update_devicetwin(device_id,device_name, connection_string)
         
    except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HsF3HQO.png  https://i.imgur.com/ZxuSWPK.png

Answer (score 0):

The error `ConnectionDroppedError` when trying to send telemetry messages to Azure IoT Hub. This error indicates an unexpected disconnection from the MQTT broker.

> you need to look into one of the [Cloud 2 Device features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance) of IoT Hub. Depending on your scenario you can use one of the following: Cloud 2 Device messages, Twins or Methods. IoT Hub exposes APIs on the back-end side (easily used with the Service Client SDKs) allowing to use any of [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525323/can-i-send-a-message-to-a-group-of-azure-iot-hub-devices-connected-via-mqtt-webs).

```py
import asyncio
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubDeviceClient

class AzureIoTHubClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self._device_client = None

    async def connect_device(self, connection_string):
        try:
            if not self._device_client or not self._device_client.connected:
                self._device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string)
                await self._device_client.connect()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while connecting to Azure IoT Hub: {e}")

    async def send_message(self, message_payload):
        try:
            if self._device_client and self._device_client.connected:
                await self._device_client.send_message(message_payload)
                print("Message sent to IoT Hub")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while sending message to IoT Hub: {e}")

    async def disconnect_device(self):
        try:
            if self._device_client and self._device_client.connected:
                await self._device_client.disconnect()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred while disconnecting from IoT Hub: {e}")


async def main():
    connection_string = "HostName=<your-hub-name>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=<your-device-id>;SharedAccessKey=<your-shared-access-key>"
    message_payload = "Hello from IoT device!"

    azure_client = AzureIoTHubClient()

    try:
        await azure_client.connect_device(connection_string)
        await azure_client.send_message(message_payload)

    finally:
        await azure_client.disconnect_device()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

[image]

[image]

To monitor messages sent to and from devices in Azure IoT Hub using Azure CLI, you can use the `az iot hub monitor-events` command.

```bash
az iot hub monitor-events --hub-name <hub-name> --device-id <device-id>
```

[image]